# JavaFX: Run ChangeListener

Tags: javafx, changelistener

Ho can I run the change method inside `ChangeListener` in the initialization.
Since it only run when changes happen. For example I have a `TextField` that I want to set it's value to 0 when it's empty, and I do it like this:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
                textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
            }

            if (newValue.isEmpty())
                textField.setText("0");

        }
    });
```

But at the start of the application the changed method is not called. So how to work around this issue?

Comment: What text does it have when the application starts?

Comment: it's empty, but the TextField is one of many cases, another case is a Button that I want to set it's disable property according to a TableView selected item.

Comment: But if it's empty, then the listener would change it to `"0"`. So why not initialize it to `"0"`? Similarly with other controls: just initialize them so their state is consistent with your requirements. (Note that with the `Button`, you could use a binding instead: `button.disableProperty().bind(tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull());`).

Comment: As an aside, for the code you posted, the accepted way to veto or modify changes to the text field is using a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).

Comment: I thought that setting it would be bad code.

Comment: Why? You're (implicitly or explicitly) setting it to `""` already.

Comment: Why, is because I still do not make a difference between bad and good except that I know hard coding stuff is bad. But it seem I did hard code it in the end

Comment: Could you post and answer with a 'TextFormatter'

Comment: Added answer with `TextFormatter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to access a listener added to a property. Obviously you could just keep a reference to it:

```
ChangeListener<String> textFieldListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

    if (!newValue.matches("\\d*")) {
        textField.setText(newValue.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
    }

    if (newValue.isEmpty())
        textField.setText("0");

};

textField.textProperty().addListener(textFieldListener);
textFieldListener.changed(null, null, textField.getText());
```

or, perhaps more naturally, just move the actual functionality to a different method:

```
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> vetoTextFieldChanges());
vetoTextFieldChanges();

// ...

private void vetoTextFieldChanges() {
    String newText = textField.getText();
    if (!newText.matches("\\d*")) {
        textField.setText(newText.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
    }

    if (newText.isEmpty())
        textField.setText("0");
}
```

Note that the whole approach of watching for changes and then modifying them if they are inconsistent with your business logic is not very satisfactory. For example, if you have other listeners registered with the property, they may see the intermediate (invalid) values of the text. The supported way to do this is to use a [`TextFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html). The `TextFormatter` both allows you to veto changes that are requested to the text, *before* the `textProperty()` is updated, and to convert the text to an appropriate value. So in your case you could do:

```
UnaryOperator<TextFormatter.Change> filter = change -> {

    // remove any non-digit characters from inserted text:
    if (! change.getText().matches("\\d*")) {
        change.setText(change.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
    }

    // if new text is empty, replace all text with "0":
    if (change.getControlNewText().isEmpty()) {
        change.setRange(0, change.getControlText().length());
        change.setText("0");
    }

    return change ;
};

TextFormatter<Integer> formatter = new TextFormatter<Integer>(new IntegerStringConverter(), 0, filter);
textField.setTextFormatter(formatter);
```

Now you can use the formatter to get the (numeric) values directly via the formatter's `value` property, and bind them to your model, etc:

```
// assume model is a data model and valueProperty() returns a Property<Integer>:
formatter.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(model.valueProperty());
```

Note that a binding like this will both update the formatter (and consequently the text field) when the model changes, and will also initialize it depending on your model value (thus providing a solution for your original question).